# Passing safe parameters to function or letting function check it?

Tags: php, function, error-handling, argument-passing

Please consider code below

```
<?php
$a = '';

echo empty($a) ? '' : substr($a, 0, 1); // Prints: ''
echo substr($a, 0, 1); // Prints: ''
```

Which "echo" is better? In first one always $a will be checked and substr will run normally and in second one, substr checks $a internally and may trigger some notice errors.

Answer (score 0):

The first one is better.

You always need to prevent errors / warnings / notices.

Although I wouldn't even use the one-liner just for readability.

Answer (score 0):

The input string must be one character or longer. So it is better to check before.
Please check :   http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

Answer (score 0):

The most important part is that you differ between input and output variables:

```
$input['a'] = '';

$output['a'] = empty($input['a']) ? '' : substr($input['a'], 0, 1);

echo $output['a'];
```

How you write the validation is your business, it should deal with all edge cases and should not trigger any errors/warnings.

**Edit:** If you're concerned to reduce the number of function calls, the following snippet does not make use of any functions, only one language constructs:

```
$a = empty($a[0])?'':$a[0];
echo $a;
```

Comment: You should really consider shifting your focus to first prevent errors and next performance.

Comment: +1 to what PeeHaa comments, performance is relative, but security is not. Security includes that your code will safely execute (the security that your script runs regardless of the input values passed to it). If it doesn't, performance is useless, because it won't perform at all.

Comment: Thank you guys. I really understand your words but my purpose is about internal and external checking, not leaving alerts. You would think a function which doesn't make any alert instead of substr...